# SymmetricDS: real time synchronisation of MySQL with PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, synchronization, symmetricds

I need to move a huge system from MySQL to PostgreSQL. This cannot be done in one go, which is why I need a robust (real time or near real time) data bi-directional synchronisation solution between MySQL and PostgreSQL. SymmetricDS looks like a tool that could solve my problem. However...

Would SymmetricDS be capable of this? The documentation is extensive and it doesn't clearly state that it would work in this particular situation. I'd like to know that this is at least possible, before spending a few weeks and hitting a dead end.

Comment: Why do you need bi-directional synchronisation, what's holding you back from just having a single master? How do you intend to deal with update conflicts across the two servers?

Comment: @RichardHuxton It's because I have to manually convert a lot of queries from MySQL to PostgreSQL, while the system is live (can't just freeze it), so both databases would be used at the same time... Update conflicts would be avoided selectively converting queries that can potentially create conflicting records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SymmetricDS is capable of this.

I've configured a bi-directional sync between MySQL and PostgreSQL. It shouldn't take a couple of weeks to setup a test.  Start off by syncing a single table without dependencies.

For a one time import export it is also possible to use the SymmetricDS DbImport DbExport tools.